# Is there any geometric interpretation of a non-invertable matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

My question is basicly what the title says.
Also is there any non-invertable n by n matrices except the all 0-element matrices?

Thanks in advance. =)

Comment: Any set of $n$ linearly dependent vectors would make a non-invertable matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course there is!

Remember that an invertible transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is precisely one where $\det(T)\ne 0$. One can then prove that for $V\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ one has that $\text{Vol}(T(V))=\det(T)\text{Vol}(V)$ (where $\text{Vol}$ denotes the signed volume). Thus, an invertible linear transformation is precisely a transformation which takes non-zero volume regions to non-zero volume regions. Intuitively, this means that a "three dimensional" object isn't crushed to a lower-dimensional object--this is translated back to normal algebra land by saying that $T$ has non-trivial kernel (it crushes some dimension to zero).